# Particle Lifetime Info doesn't work on metaballs

Tags: particles, metaballs

I am working on an animation of water droplets moving upward ("evaporating"). I am trying to animate material transparency based on particle lifetime. Here's my node setup:

[image: Node setup]

It works when using a simple sphere as a particle:

[image: Sphere particles]

However, I want to fake water bubbles, so I'm using a metaball as a particle. The effect is gone:

[image: Metaballs as particles]

Why it doesn't work with metaballs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work with metaballs because they are actually just empties. Then a mesh is formed with SDF functions. Therefore the mesh you see is actually one object/instance so it doesn't carry separate particle data. The object Texture Coordinate can still be used for a similar, but definitely not same effect.

[image]